# How should we authenticate a 1st party login request in an application that allows 3rd party login via OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, api, authentication

We're working on a new API that we wish to secure with api tokens. These tokens are tied to a user and an application. These 3rd party applications use OAuth to authenticate themselves (using and app_id and app_secret). This works great.

However, we have our own mobile app which will also consume this API. Obviously I'd like to avoid having the user get asked the familiar "would you like to allow this app to use your account" when performing a login. Obviously we can't embed a secret in the app, (hence pure OAuth would be unsuitable for this). However, I don't want to create an API endpoint to which a username and password can be sent since this would effectively bypass the OAuth scheme entirely.

On the web site, we can just dump the api token into the DOM after a regular form submission, and allow the Angular app to use it from there; but this simply isn't practical in a mobile app.

So my question is; how can we securely identify login requests from our own mobile application? How does (for example) Facebook know that it's the Facebook app supplying the username and password when authenticating, and not some 3rd party application?